# Is it possible to use unordered::map::find if the map's key is a pointer to string?

Tags: c++, pointers, unordered-map

I have this map:

```
using namespace std; // just for readability

unordered_map<shared_ptr<string>, whatever_type> map;
```

Then a string comes from the outside. Can I use `find` somehow?

```
map.find(someInputString); // won't work, keys are wrapped by pointers
```

Is using a loop the only option?

P.S. I am interested if there is some special signature of the `find` method, or another method to do this, to avoid a loop.

Comment: I strongly advice **against** using `shared_ptr`'s as keys. I can't imagine why it might be desirable.

Comment: @SergeyA What if the strings are quite large, and they are also stored in other places

Comment: You can have `unordered_map` with a custom hashcode and comparator. I don't see other way for this to work fast. I never did this, but probably you have to define your own wrapper class for keys.

Comment: @SergeyA makes sense, but hope dies last :-) that's why I asked

Comment: You probably will have to use custom hash function and custom compare function which would dereference pointers. You would probably want to use transparent allocators. Also shared pointers make it super weird, can you change the design to use plain non-owning pointer?

Comment: How are you comparing these `shared_ptr`s? By identity?

Comment: @T.C. by dereferencing if that'd be supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work with regular map. Here is the code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct PtrCompare {
    using is_transparent = bool;
    auto operator() (const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& rhs) const {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
    auto operator() (const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
        return *lhs < rhs;
    }
    auto operator() (const std::string& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& rhs) const {
        return lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

std::map<std::shared_ptr<std::string>, int, PtrCompare>  my_hash;

auto check(const std::string& x) {
    return my_hash.find(x);
}
```

It uses the feature of transparent comparators, which is available on C++14. However, transparent comparators for unordered maps are only available with C++20, and thus, my solution doesn't work with unordered maps.

The way to make it work with non-transparent comparator for unordered maps would be to still use custom hasher and comparator, which would compare arguments after dereferencing them, but create a shared pointer from a string you want to compare with, and find using this shared pointer. To me this solution is super ugly, so I am not suggesting this.

Comment: Do you mean transparent *comparators*?

Comment: Wow. My knowledge of C++ is so low I can't understand this solution (and its performance characteristics) yet. But, thank you! I hope I'll improve my knowledge soon to understand and probably use this soon enough.